# How to do I write custome apache rules for urls from a view folder and remove the .PHP

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have literally looked everywhere to try and understand Apache rules and writing better. What I am trying to achieve is fairly simple. I want to leave my index.php in the root, and for each additional page/view I want to keep them in a view directory and all views always display without the .php extension.

The second thing I am trying to achieve however, is I want to keep all my other pages in a view folder, and maybe even have folders within to keep views organized, but display the url without the /view like: something.com/about NOT somthing.com/views/about

Lastly, 
If I place folders within the view, I want to decide which will display like: something.com/about && somthing.com/blog/winners

This is as close as I have gotten:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

# Url renaming
RewriteRule ^contact$ contact.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your existing rule with this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/view/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ view/$1.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: anubhava Thank you but unfortunately it did not work. For whatever reason Apache will not read or find whatever views I have in views directory. Yesterday I had it working by doing this: ^case-studies$ views/case-studies.php [L]
However now, unless I place all views in my root it will not show it.. Any ideas?

Comment: I did, t is not working, I am wondering if there is some sorto of apache cache that needs to be disabled? I am using mamp, any other thoughts?

Comment: I've also tested it on MAMP. You will need to provide information about your setup. Try answering all the questions.  Q1. What URL are you entering in your browser? Q2. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q3. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q4. Where is above .htaccess located? Q5. Did you make sure that `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` are enabled?